# What is limiting high frequency ultrasound from being high power

Tags: high-frequency, ultrasound, transducer

This is mostly just our of curiosity and I feel like I may be missing something basic, but what is limiting ultrasond transducers in the range of 500kHz-MHz from not outputting higher power like the low frequency high power transducers (20-80kHz)
Is it a materials issue? I can't find the answer anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: I would guess the medium itself, which would have to be liquid and then solid. ~100kHz is still used in industrial applications, which means there is enough power to do mechanical work. MHz frequencies would have very specialized uses like imaging on small scales. At even higher extremes you are getting into behaviors of crystal lattices.

Comment: Probably expense. The 'H' in Hz is capitalized by the way because it is someone's name.

Comment: ... but SI units named after a person are lowercase when spelt out. The first letter of the symbol is capitalised.

Comment: If you notice, I did capitalize it the first time, got lazy. Pete, this doesn't really answer the question of why I can generate higher power in the MHz range but I still appreciate your comment.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Hertz

Comment: @Hatsrow - Sorry, I don't know the answer to that. The "power" devices I have encountered at the high kHz range I *think* used coils rather than piezos, coupled to solid parts with a resonant mechanical design, but I have not been in the business of building those, they were black-box modules to me. I have some side interest in this so keeping an eye on it.

Comment: `I did capitalize it the first time, got lazy` ... why have you not corrected your errors instead of posting a comment that tries to explain the reason? ... less typing

Comment: Your question is a bit hazy. Is 1 kW+ at 1.3MHz "high power"?

Comment: Spehro: I would think so, it seems to me at frequencies above 100 kHz don't typically output more than maybe a few hundred Watts. And at the MHz rage it seems to by in the mW range. What is preventing a transducer from outputting, say, 500W at 1MHz?

Answer (score 0):

Thickness of transduser is matter. Frequency is proportional to lenth of wave. Highest frequency, shorter wave, thicker plate. thick plate may be destroyed by big amplitude. And, of cause, another factors, like type of material.

Comment: I guess that's what I'm wondering. At a shorter wavelength and higher frequency, whats keeping the amplitude and thus power low. You might of answered this; amplitude at higher frequencies would have too much stress? A material limit?

Comment: Yes. It is usually piezoceramic. Fragile.